# Icon font not displaying on iOS 12

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uifont, ios12

I have an issue with an icon font not displaying on iOS 12 (it works perfectly fine on iOS <= 11). A few more details on what I've found and how we use the font:

1) The font is properly included in the project and it appears when NSlogging `[UIFont familyNames]` and `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:iconFontFamilyName]`

2) I'm accessing the icons using the \u notation: `label.text = @"\uXXXX"`. When XXXX does **NOT** exist in the font, the app displays the "question-mark-in-a-square", indicating (correctly) that the code does not exist. However, if the code **DOES** exist in the font, then the app displays nothing at all - the respective element appears blank.

Is there something we're missing here?

Comment: Have you tried your font in the other places?

Comment: question-mark-in-a-square is just a symbol too. Probably your glyphs have no got proper sizes.

Comment: @Vyacheslav the same icon font plays quite nicely on iOS 11 (or lower) so I'm *guessing* this is an iOS 12 issue

Comment: I know that my custom font (several glyphs) are correctly shown in iOS 10, not in iOS 11. I would suggest checking glyphs.

Comment: How are you creating the font, and in what file format?

Comment: @jjrscott It's a .ttf file created with IcoMoon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary, the issue is most likely with Icomoon's font generation; specifically the types of [`cmap`](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6cmap.html) encoding subtables. I would suggest two actions:

1. Test this hypothesis by using a font conversion tool (such as https://onlinefontconverter.com) to convert your `ttf` file to `otf` (which is also supported by iOS).
2. If your glyph displays then continue to use your new `otf` file while raising the issue with IcoMoon directly.

I remember having a similar issue when playing around with on-device font generation in my [MinimumRubber project](https://github.com/jjrscott/MinimumRubber/blob/master/MinimumRubber/MRFont.m). I found that careful choice of platform identifier and platform-specific encoding identifier were required for both `UILabel` and `UITextView` to display the glyph. It does not surprise me that Apple has refactored this area of code